# Do the various verbs pronounced つく differ in intonation?

Tags: words, pronunciation, pitch-accent, intonation

> **Related:** [Dissecting つく verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2070/384)

There are many verbs which are pronounced つく, and I was simply wondering: **Do their intonation patterns differ?**

If so, **what are the intonation patterns of the most common forms of つく in Tokyo dialect?**

Common: 付く、着く、吐く、突く

Comment: I pronounce all of them as High-Low, but this may be either the Nagoya dialect or the Tokyo dialect.  Someone should be able to answer more clearly and definitely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NHK pronunciation dictionary prescribes that:

1. 付く, 着く, （羽根を）撞く, （職に）就く, （嘘を）吐く, （位に）即く, （明かりが）点く, and （餅を）搗く all have the accent on the first or second mora (with first preferred: HL)
2. 突く has no accent (so in isolation it is LH, but note that this is not the same as accent-on-the-second-mora LH when other words follow)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is [this book](http://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/english/book/book_98040101.html) the one you're referencing?

Comment: Sort of. Yes, it's the NHK 編 日本語発音アクセント辞典, but I have an edition published in 1985 with a blue-and-gray cover that claims to be a 改訂新版.