# Different permutations of 気

Tags: word-choice, etymology, set-phrases

Lots of words/expressions/phrases use 気 in one way or another. For example 気をつけて, 気味, 気になる, 気がつく, 気がする, 天気 etc...

Is there a reference somewhere for the seemingly more "interesting" phrases (like the ones using つく as described in [Dissecting つく verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2070/dissecting-%e3%81%a4%e3%81%8f-verbs)). By reference i mean translation, sample usage and maybe even an explanation of why it means what it means.

Comment: Don't forget all the instances where it's used as a noun suffix.

Comment: Hard to forget stuff you don't know :) Are you talking about something like 人気がある?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try looking for these phrases or words with these sites:

http://www.alc.co.jp/

http://ejje.weblio.jp/

If you become a member of http://lang-8.com/ (it is free), you can ask native speakers for examples or explanations.

Comment: I was looking for a more formal description, so I am not sure that native speakers can be of great help here. Weblio is nice, but I could not find what I was looking for.